# Is there a filtration method that can be used to separate solids and liquids without filter paper?

Tags: filtering

I am looking for a filter that can can be reused indefinitely like a strainer with very small gaps. Does such an equipment exist?

Comment: Glass filters are a thing.

Comment: Which objection to indefinitely as there is always the trouble  of clogging (Remember inkjet printers.) of small pores. Reverse washing helps just partially, can prolong the filter life, but it has its limits.

Comment: Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the StackExchange network.    [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Describe the question well, search, think, refer and summarize.  Well elaborated questions have higher probability to  receive acceptable answers.

Comment: This is what you are looking for  https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/glass-funnel-filter-sintered-glass-disc/11922148

Comment: The [Mr. Coffee Larger Gold Tone Reusable Coffee Filter](https://www.mrcoffee.com/accessories/coffee-and-water-filters/mr.-coffee-larger-gold-tone-reusable-coffee-filter/SAP_2104642.html) is the answer.

Comment: Part of the trouble with the use of the word "filtration" is that it implies a specific method of separating solids from liquids. If you phrased the question without using the word "filtration" you might get more answers, for example some processes might use centrifugal processes (like Dyson vacuum cleaners) which can be used as both batch processes (a standard lab centrifuge) or continuously (in some industrial cyclones or, indeed, vacuum cleaners).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You neither state the size of the particles to retain/remove, nor the chemistry of the suspension you deal with; in this regard, your question should be improved.  E.g., is the solution acidic/neutral/basic, absence/presence of strong oxydants, temperature and intended processing parameters equally are worth an addition to yield a more specific answer.

The possibly most strainer-like approach is the use of metal or plastic *as a sieve* which may be performed in batches, or continuously.  The filter bed may be fix, or moving  as for e.g., centrifugal sieves / essoreuses:

[image]

(image edited; image credit to https://www.palamaticprocess.com/bulk-handling-equipment/centrifugal-sieve).

The material of the sieve may be e.g., metal (like a tea infuser, the oil filter in a car), plastic (like your essoreuse in the kitchen), or gravel (like the sand filters in a water purification plant).  This may be complemented by filtration across a fabric like cotton (removal of crud in artisanal cheese making), or polymers (polypropylene, polyamide) as seen for belt and pan filters acting by gravity or vacuum:

[image]

(image credit to http://www.solidliquid-separation.com/VacuumFilters/vacuum.htm)

Comment: I'm think of separating pasta and hot water with a strainer. Those strainers can be cleaned in the dishwasher, but I wouldn't say they last indefinitely...